# how to save Seaborn's FacetGrid in a multiple page pdf file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

I have written the code below to plot multiple figures using FacetGrid of seaborn ( sns.lmplot ). Saving figure in pdf format will result in a 1 page pdf file. I was wondering if someone could help me to have only like 3 rows and 4 columns per page and also have them all plotted in a single pdf with multiple pages?

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

g = sns.lmplot('index','value',data=merged, col="station", hue="flow type",col_wrap=3,height=2,aspect=2,legend_out=False,fit_reg=False,sharex=False,sharey=False)
#g.savefig('50%_flow_duration_curves_cariboo.pdf', format='png', dpi=1000)


g.set_xlabels("exceedence %")
g.set_ylabels("flow")
```

here is how it looks like now: 
[image]

Comment: You will need to create 3 individual figures which you can then append to a pdf via [pdfpages](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/multipage_pdf.html).